# limit with a parametrical integral $ \lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{sin(x)}{(1 + x)^n} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, limits

I need help in calculating this strange limit.

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{sin(x)}{(1 + x)^n} dx
$$

Comment: What have you attempted? Could you show your work?

Answer (score 3):

We can substitute $x=\frac{t}{n}$:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{(1 + x)^n} dx=\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(t/n)}{(1 + \frac tn)^n}\frac{1}{n}dt$$

Now in the denominator we get $(1+\frac{t}{n})^n$, and we're taking the limit $n\to\infty$; this becomes $e^t$, so that we get (also take the $\frac 1n$ out of the integral):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(t/n)}{e^t}dt$$

Now also see that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(\frac{t}{n})=t$ so that we get

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t}{e^t}dt$$

Now the $n$'s are gone so we can write

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t}{e^t}dt$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: So this holds for any function $f$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)/x = 1$, not just $\sin$.

Comment: This leads to a correct outcome but *why* are we really allowed to replace $\left(1+t/n\right)^n$ with $e^t$ *before* considering the limit as $n\to +\infty$ (presumably, through the dominated convergence theorem)? It looks like $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} T_n(f_n) = (\lim T_n)(\lim f_n)$$ is used, but that is not granted to hold unconditionally.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n^{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\sin\pars{x} \over \pars{1 + x}^{n}}\,\dd x} & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n^{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\sin\pars{x}\exp\pars{-n\ln\pars{1 + x}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n^{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}
x\,\exp\pars{-nx}\,\dd x} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
x\,\exp\pars{-x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{1}
\end{align}

> See [Laplace's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method).